# Anime: teen (boy or girl) goes into a kind of floating city (?) and there are fights between the teens

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm searching for an anime that I watched... a long time ago, in France. The only thing that stays in my head is ***the possibility*** of the number **9** being in the title.

I remember some scenes in the anime :

- A teen/child in the snow who (I think) is find by a group of other teens that live in a floating city. They take him with them.
- He (or her but I think it's he) wakes up and get to know every person living here but something is wrong with these teens, causing some of them to try to kill each other.

*From here I'm not sure of myself and it could mislead you.*

- They may be in conflict with people outside this floating city.
- They broke in two groups after all the problems and some of them leave the floating city.

I can remember one girl from the anime. She has long brown hair and seem serious and mature.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but could you please take a look at [this guide on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), and [this one on anime](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/98028), see if that makes you remember anything more, that you could [edit] in? For example - when is "a long time ago"? (2010, 1980, etc) Did you watch that on TV, if so any memory of the channel? (vaguely sounds like something Mangas or M6 would broadcast...) And anything else you could remember. Everything might help. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'm actually extremely happy and surprised cause it's been two weeks since i started searching and i couldn't find it but... i just did. The anime I was searchinf for is **Norn9** !
I'm sorry if i posted an unecessary new topic but i was so certain not to be able to find it :'(

Comment: No worries! Please post it as an answer (the textbox at the bottom of the page)! :) it's the "proper" way to do things, and will enable people looking for the same anime will get the information as well!

Answer (score 8):

This question has found an answer !

The anime is NORN9, here is **the trailer**:

And **the summary**: In a futuristic era, "The World" is a peace-bringing entity. Though no one knows its location, it has watched over Earth for so long that war has become merely a fable. The airship Norn's task is to deliver nine ability users to The World.

After collecting the last person, Norn takes off. Included onboard are eight men and three women—Koharu, who has finally escaped her loneliness and detests her destructive power; Mikoto Kuga, born to a noble family, who uses her barrier skill to protect the Norn and those it carries; and Nanami Shiranui, whose ability only brings pain, and who wishes to die for a past sin she has committed. While en route, suspicions arise amongst the passengers when they realize there are too many people onboard.

As they try to determine who has snuck aboard, the ship is attacked by an unknown assailant aiming to stop the Norn's progress at all costs. From this chaos arises questions: why were they granted powers, and what must they do once they reach The World?

Comment: Nice self-answer! You will be able to "accept" it in 48 hours, by clicking the checkmark on the left. Please do! :) In the meantime, maybe you'd want to see if you can provide an answer to [some of these unanswered anime-identifications](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Banime%5D+answers%3A0)?